# Python - Import error: DLL Load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qgis

I'm using QGIS + Python with the PyQt4 library.

Currently I'm running Python 2.7 32bit in Windows 7 64 bit (I know these by executing sys.architecture())

I download the PyQt4 library from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download for 32bits architecture.

Then I add to the PATH variable: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;D:/Program Files/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis/bin;D:/Program Files/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis/python;
And set PYTHONPATH = D:/Program Files/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis/python;

The odd thing here is that I manage to make it work yesterday. But now when I want to run it again this error appears:

Edit: code error added

`File "main.py"
   from qgis.core import *
   File "D:\PRogram Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36 in <module>
      from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
   File "D:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py, line 34 in <module>
      from qgis._core import *
ImportErrro: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application`

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31RKb.jpg)

Any help would be helpfull

Comment: Just guessing, but try to use quotes for paths where you have a space. Do you start it from a `batch` or what does `%1` mean?

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: @MattDMo sorry, now is the error in the question