# How to set up qgis Python environment properly

Tags: python, conda

I would like to set up a Python environment where I can do the following

- run the qgis API from outside the qgis application
- be able to install other Python libraries using `pip`, `conda` or other tools

I tried to follow the solution suggested in the [qgis cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html) under "Running custom applications". Basically they recommend to modify the system `PATH` variable and the `PYTHONPATH` variable. When I did this however I had a problem similar to many other people (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66889/qgis-plugins-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259602/from-qgis-core-import-importerror-dll-load-failed) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682677/python-import-error-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)).

So then I found out that `conda` has a [dedicated library](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis) which I proceeded to install. But this also presents me with an issue... `conda list` shows `qgis`  as one of the installed libraries, but when I go `python` then `import qgis` I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: NoModule named 'qgis'`

Also I found no instructions about this in the Conda website or from search engines, so I'm not sure if this library even really works.

I would like to avoid manually setting Windows environment variables and set this one up the proper way. How do I do it?

Comment: Upon further though I think this might be more appropriate to ask in the Geographic Information Systems community. How can I move it there?

Comment: I want to bring this thread back to life as I am having the same problems.  Any input please??

Comment: My main problem was that I wanted to be able to develop compileable pyqt applications which make use of the qgis API. I had a strong opinion that libraries which host such an application must all live in the same environment, and it infuriated me that the qgis API would not comply with this. However after some experimentation with pyinstaller I realized that this is not strictly necessary. Pyinstaller works based on module imports and not environments. I think it possible (though difficult) to build an application which used qgis/ other envs or libraries. Provided the spec file is correct.